# How to get the status of processes in real-time?

Tags: node.js, process, operating-system

I have a requirement, I want to develop a software like below to monitor the process status.
[image]

In my case, I use pm2 to manage the processes, but as we know `pm2 list` can list the processes managed by pm2, it can not provide real-time status of its processes.

if I want to get the effect of real-time monitoring, I only can round robin this command.
so, is there any other recommended to achieve my goal?

---

**Edit-01**

Whether there is any API of OS we can use to get the process status?

Comment: I mean get the status of process in real time(websocket), not use HTTP for round robin.

Comment: in my case, I use pm2 manage the processes, but when I want to know the process status, I will execute `pm2 list` then get the result, this is not use websocket way.